# Why benzene has more heat of hydrogenation than cyclohexene?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, stability

According to me, benzene is more stable than cyclohexene due to its aromatic nature. Therefore the heat of hydrogenation of cyclohexene should be more than benzene (because I read that heat of hydrogenation is inversely proportional to stability).
But then also the heat of hydrogenation of benzene is more than that of cyclohexene.
Does it indicate the idea that non-aromatic compounds may be more stable than aromatic ones?

Comment: Please include relevant data (and sources where appropriate) for these types of questions.

Comment: I think this is relevant to your question as it seems you neglect the different degree of unsaturation. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/108726/why-total-heat-of-hydrogenation-of-1-3-cyclohexadiene-is-more-than-that-of-benze